# iOS get stuck in instantiation dependency without failing

Tags: swift, instantiation, static-variables

If I've something that looks like

```
class Foo {
  static shared = Foo()
  init() {
    print("init Foo")
    let _ = Bar.shared
  }
}

class Bar {
  static shared = Bar()
  init() {
    print("init Bar")
    let _ = Foo.shared
  }
}

// somwehere else:
let _ = Foo.shared
```

then the app gets stuck. Nothing happens. I understand that this design is wrong, but I'm wondering why the app is not crashing, reporting an error or at least printing a loop. The above code print

```
init Foo
init Bar
```

and that's it, showing that it is not looping but just getting stuck. An idea on what's happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Swift, static type properties are initialized lazily, in a guaranteed thread-safe manner.

NOTE in [Type Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID264)

> Stored type properties are lazily initialized on their first access.
>   They are guaranteed to be initialized only once, even when accessed by
>   multiple threads simultaneously, and they do not need to be marked
>   with the lazy modifier.

This *only once* feature utilizes `dispatch_once`-like thing (or exactly itself) which needs mutual exclusion.

When initializing `Foo.shared`, the lock for `Foo.shared` is locked. And while it's locked, `Bar.shared` needs to be initialized, so the lock for `Bar.shared` is locked. And while both locked, `Foo.shared` needs to be initialized, but the lock for it is already locked, so wait there till the lock is freed...

We call this situation a **dead-lock**.

Comment: Lock makes sense. Is it excepted that the app shows no error or doesn't crash for such dead-lock situation? Does the app even know there is a dead-lock or is it just not seeing it and waiting for things to resolve? To me it sounds quite like an error that should be reported and fails loudly

Comment: @Guig, general dead-lock detection is sort of very hard, but, yes, in some typical and simple cases, dead-locks can be detected in compile time, and some sort of debugging runtime would be able to detect dead-locks at runtime. Maybe such features are something "not-yet" or getting low priority. You can write a feature request through [Apple's Bug Reporter](http://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/). Without such features, apps are expected to wait forever...